# Find multiple differences between two strings

Tags: design-patterns, distance, levenshtein-distance

I want to find the differences between two strings. For example, if

```
line1 = "My name is ABC"
line2 = "My age is xyz"
```

Then I should be able to get the differences that name - age and ABC - xyz.

I think I can use Levenshtein distance, but can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$line1 = "My name is ABC";
$line2 = "My age is xyz";

$matchlen = strspn($line1, $line2);

// remove 1st non-matching char
$same = substr($line1, 0, $matchlen - 1);

// include 1st non-matching char
$diff = substr($line2, $matchlen - 1);

printf("Same: [%s]\nDiff: [%s]", $same, $diff);
?>
```

Comment: That will not work correctly, because the first difference is not matching in length: `name : 4` and `age : 3`